# How To Query nested mongoDB with $or query in nested field of arrays in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to query mongoDB collection to fetch and match a specific date range and a specific array of ids, such as brachIds, or servicesIds.

I want the query if it finds this result to return it, so that i can validate if a request already exists in that collection by a specific user.

But whenever I pass array values to the `$or [{}]` segment of the query, no result comes back when i use `$all`

what am I doing wrong?

Below code that is working and retrieving the document:

```
 db.collection("collection")
                    .find({'f.from': {$eq: moment(from, "YYYY-MM-DD").startOf('day').format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]")},
                        'f.to': {$eq: moment(to, "YYYY-MM-DD").startOf('day').format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]")},
                     
                        $or: [{'f.b': {$eq: b }},{'f.g': { $eq: s }},{'f.s': {$eq: g }}]})
                    .toArray()
                    .then(result => {

                           
                            if (result.length) {

                                resolve(result)

                            } else {
                         
                                resolve(result)

                            }
                        }).catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must make sure that your parameters are arrays, so you must convert them as follows:

```
    if (!branchesIds ) {
    branchesIds = [branchesIds];
}

if (!servicesIds ) {
    servicesIds = [servicesIds];
}

if (!groupOfBranchesIds ) {
    groupOfBranchesIds = [groupOfBranchesIds];
}
```

Then your query should use the `$in`:

```
find({'filter.dateRange.from': {$eq: moment(from, "YYYY-MM-DD").startOf('day').format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]")},
    'filter.dateRange.to': {$eq: moment(to, "YYYY-MM-DD").startOf('day').format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]")},
    $or: [{'filter.branchesIds': { $in: branchesIds }},{'filter.groupOfBranchesIds': { $in: groupOfBranchesIds }},{'filter.servicesIds': { $in: servicesIds }}]})
.sort({_created_at: -1})
.toArray()
```

This should now work. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, i tried this and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

you use **$eq** instead of **$in,** use **$in** when you want to do operations on arrays

```
$or: [{'filter.branchesIds': {$in: branchesIds }},{'filter.groupOfBranchesIds': { $in: servicesIds }},{'filter.servicesIds': {$in: groupOfBranchesIds }}]})
```